# Hosting multiple websites on the same server - Prevention from DoS

Tags: denial-of-service, ddos, shared-hosting

I have an server which contains around 4 instances hosted on it. I am aware that if a DoS attack happens on one of the instances it will take down all the other instances too. How to prevent such a failure and harden my server?

Comment: Are the individual instances of the site virtualized?

Comment: @KingJohnno I am sorry, virtualized means?

Comment: Virtualization, refers to the act of creating a virtual (rather than actual) version of something.  You can virtualize the instance of the Operating system - meaning that each OS is effectively a server in its own right.

Comment: Ok. This server is assigned to me for testing purpose. Am not sure whether it is virtual hosting or not? Could you please explain the answer in both cases as an answer if you can?

Comment: Check if your Server is a VPS (virtual Private Server) or not.  

I will do some research into this, and come back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a single aggregated link, even though it's 4 way virtualised host. Up to a certain level, you cannot prevent dos attacks, so what you'll be trying to do is to keep the service up for legitimate users, and sinkhole everyone else.

This depends on the budget that you have on hand to do this, which in most small-medium enterprises is close to zero. Magic bullets are not possible and you'll need a layered solution in place.

Comment: Can port forwarding used for this?

Comment: The point is, if your bandwidth is saturated by a ddos, you cannot forward anything. If the ddos is a starvation attack, then bringing anything else online can conceivably lessen the load.

Answer (score 1):

If you run more than one server on the host, they will share the resources and an attack to one site will impact the others. There's no way to prevent it working only with your server. You must work outside of it.

You could have another server in another provider in cold standby, and change DNS records of the attacked site to point to this backup server, so the traffic will be redirected and your *innocent* sites will not suffer.

If you don't have a backup server, you can sinkhole the DNS records of the attacked site. This way you stop the attack, the *innocent* sites don't suffer, but the attacked site goes dark until you restore the DNS settings.

You could ask your upstream provider to help you identify the attackers, and they can employ their *anti-DoS* tools to help you.